# javascript not bringing user to redirected page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi so im trying to build something where a user gets re directed to a new page so here's my code

```js
var blue = ["question1button1", "question1button2"];
var secondquestion = ["question2button1", "question2button2"];
var button1, button2, button3, button4 = false;

function myFunction() {
    var favorite = blue[Math.floor(Math.random() * blue.length)];
    var postmessage = favorite;
    document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = postmessage;

    if (postmessage == "test"){
     button1 = true;
     alert("test");
    }
    if (postmessage == "test1"){
        button2 = true;
     alert("test1");
    }
    if (postmessage == "test2"){
        button3 = true;
     alert("test2");
    }

    if (postmessage == "test3"){
        button4 = true;
     alert("test3");
    }
}

function next(){
    if(button1 == true || button2 == true){
        window.location = "test/test1.html";
    }
    else{
        alert("choose a side");
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" value="myvalue" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="next1" value="gonext" onclick="next()">next</button>
```

so my question here is i have pressed a button but it's still telling me the else statement

Answer (score 0):

Its because your condition in postmessage is wrong.. Change `postmessage == "test"` to `postmessage == "question1button2"` or `postmessage == "question1button1"`

Try this code..

```js
var blue = ["question1button1", "question1button2"];
var secondquestion = ["question2button1", "question2button2"];
var button1, button2, button3, button4 = false;

function myFunction() {
  var favorite = blue[Math.floor(Math.random() * blue.length)];
  var postmessage = favorite;
  document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = postmessage;

  if (postmessage == "question1button1"){
    button1 = true;
    alert("test");
  }
  if (postmessage == "question1button2"){
    button2 = true;
    alert("test1");
  }
  if (postmessage == "test2"){
    button3 = true;
    alert("test2");
  }
  if (postmessage == "test3"){
    button4 = true;
    alert("test3");
  } 
}

function next(){
  if(button1 == true || button2 == true){
    window.location = "test/test1.html";
  }
  else{
    alert("choose a side");
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" value="myvalue" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button id="next1" value="gonext" onclick="next()">next</button>
```

Comment: Oh thank you, i forgot i changed my array. Thank you very much for noticing my mistake

Comment: @TerryChen Welcome bro.. Just mark it as the answer if it solve your problem.. good luck in your project. :)